# how save data in xml file and want user can not understand what is written

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

in my project i have xml file to store and retrieve`Device` Objects
and i want user can add or delete in my xml file only by my application not manually
so i need to story data in some format user cannot understand it like viewState in asp.net `base64` or some thing else

**My Question is how i can save my data in xml file but i want user can not understand what is written**

this is my Device Class

```
public class Device
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string PeerURI { get; set; }
        public string SipURI { get; set; }
        public string FQDN { get; set; }
        public Enums.DeviceType Type { get; set; }
        public Enums.ServerTransportType TransportType { get; set; }
        public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <username>foo</username>
  <AgentName>foo1</AgentName>
  <password>foo2</password>
  <domain>go</domain>
  <peerUri>140.242.250.200</peerUri>
  <sipUri>sip:xxx@xxxxx.com</sipUri>
  <fqdn>ff.go.xxxx.com</fqdn>
  <type>2</type>
  <transportType>2</transportType>
</settings>
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The user will always be able to edit the file manually if he can find the file and he has the proper filesystem permission to edit the file.

Comment: I'd suggest the `Database` instead of `XML`.

Comment: Why don't you use binary format?

Comment: [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) / [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Comment: You can see an example in my answer. It has definitly some advantages over XML. It is not human readable, it is fast and the files are smaller.

Comment: Mare Infinitus is right... his answer may be better than mine.  The only reason I could see to using XML with Base64 encoding over the BinaryFormatter is if you need the file to be compatible across different platforms.  For example, you have a .NET app on Windows and a Java app on Linux that need to read/write the same file.  Even in that case, other binary serializers will work (ProtoBuf, as mentioned by L.B., is one that is very fast/lightweight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Binary Serialisation, the file is not human readable at all.

Here is a short example for your issue:

```
public class Enums
{
    public enum DeviceType
    {
        Mouse,
        HardDisk,
        CdRom,
    }

    public enum ServerTransportType
    {
        Udp,
        Tcp,
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Device
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string PeerURI { get; set; }
    public string SipURI { get; set; }
    public string FQDN { get; set; }
    public Enums.DeviceType Type { get; set; }
    public Enums.ServerTransportType TransportType { get; set; }
    public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
}

public class BinarySerialize
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var device = new Device();

        device.Username = "userName";
        device.AgentName = "agentName";
        device.Password = "password";
        device.Domain = "domain";
        device.PeerURI = "peerURI";
        device.SipURI = "sipURI";
        device.FQDN = "fqdn";
        device.Type = Enums.DeviceType.HardDisk;
        device.TransportType = Enums.ServerTransportType.Tcp;
        device.IsInitialized = true;

        string fileName = @"C:\temp\device.bin";
        this.Serialize(device, fileName);

        var d = this.Deserialize(fileName);
    }

    public void Serialize(Device device, string fileName)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bformatter.Serialize(stream, device);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    public Device Deserialize(string fileName)
    {
        var device = new Device();

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            device = (Device)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }

        return device;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Base64 should do.

```
String username = "foo";
byte[] EncodeAsBase64 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username);
string enc_username = System.Convert.ToBase64String(EncodeAsBase64);
```

Then use the `serializer` to store enc_username.

Comment: thanks but how i retrieve this data and how i can use Serializer to store enc_username

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for Base64 encoding the entire serialization process...

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

...

```
private void WriteToFile(Device device, string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Device));
            x.Serialize(cs, device);
        }
    }
}

private Device ReadFromFile(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Device));
            return x.Deserialize(cs) as Device;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a perfect way of combining the disadvantages of xml and binary formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anyone to be able to edit your XML data file with a text editor, either:

- You shouldn't be using XML, and should be saving this to some custom binary format, or
- You should be using [encrypted XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx).